# array resize proportionally in python

Tags: python, arrays, resize

How i resize a array in python proportionally, for example:

original:

```
1 0
0 1
```

resized:

```
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1
```

---

Code:

```
original = []

row1 = [1,0]
row2 = [0,1]

original.append(row1)
original.append(row2)

#how resize?
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this a multidimensional array (or is it a list?), or how do you separate the lines?

Comment: What you show in your example is not really just resizing but more akin to magnification of, say, an image. In any case, you need to show your code because nobody can guess how you are representing your array, and you also need to say what you've tried already and what snag specifically you're caught on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have a desire to do this with Python lists:

```
SCALE_MULTIPLE = 2  # or any positive integer
new_array = []
for orig_row in original:
    new_row = []
    for orig_elem in orig_row:
        new_row.extend([orig_elem] * SCALE_MULTIPLE)
    new_array.extend(new_row[:] for _ in range(SCALE_MULTIPLE))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :), but if the SCALE_MULTIPLE needs be a number like 1.5?

Comment: Then the transformation is not well-defined, so you're going to have to decide how you want to do that (e.g. whether you want to interpolate values that don't fall on a clean boundary, et cetera).

Comment: All right, thank you for answering the question despite it being badly formatted :), but if you have an example I would appreciate further :P